# Am I using $(this) or .click incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a simple FAQ page with answers that slideDown and Up when their questions are clicked. When the user clicks on a something with class "question" I want mytarget to become '#' + [that question's id] + 'ans' so the appropriate answer slides down.

The toggleSlide part works when I just give it an answer's ID; I'm not sure if my .click function is wrong, or my use of $(this), or both.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var qid = '';
    var mytarget = '';

    function toggleSlide() {
        if ($(mytarget).css('display') == 'none') {
            $(mytarget).slideDown(600, 'swing');
        }

        else if ($(mytarget).css('display') == 'block') {
            $(mytarget).slideUp(600, 'swing');
        }
    };

    $('.answer').hide();
    $('.question').click(function() {
        qid = $('this').id();
        mytarget = '#' + qid + 'ans';
        toggleSlide();
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() {  // shorthand for $(document).ready()...
    $('.answer').hide(); // preferably div.answer if they are all <div>s
    $('.question').click(function() {
        // no need to check what it currently is, use slideToggle
        $('#' + this.id + 'ans').slideToggle(600, 'swing');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Why is div.answer preferable to .answer?

Comment: I like this one. div.answer is NOT actually preferable, though. jsPerf can show that a plain class without the element will be faster. Also, I still like to use $(document).ready() because it's just so instantly obvious to anyone (myself or another person) reading the code that it's the document ready function. But that part is personal preference.

Comment: `$(this).attr('id')` => `this.id`.

Comment: @gdoron, does `=>` mean `equal to or greater than` or does it mean `should be converted to`?  :P  Hehe

Comment: @XyanEwing. It means greater time to execute than... :)

Comment: @GregPettit: It's been a while since I've kept up with jQuery performance, but it used to be the case that if you knew only a particular element will ever have a class the selector `element.class` is preferred because jQuery can use the native `getElementsByTagName` THEN filter by class on browsers that do not support `getElementsByClassName` (IE 6,7,8)

Comment: @PaoloBergantino I remember that being the case (or at least believing it was the case) once upon a day, too. I couldn't tell you which native method makes it not the case anymore, but here's somebody else's jsPerf (and I bet there are others; I've made one myself!): http://jsperf.com/class-vs-element-and-class

Comment: @GregPettit: That is not really an accurate test because there is only one element in the page. On an actual webpage full of many HTML elements doing a pure `.class` search is going to be slower than `div.class` according to my test at least.

Comment: That test isn't my only source, but without scouring the internet, I'm quite willing to just believe you. ;-) Or to put it another way: I have certainly NOT gone back to all of my old scripts just to change `div.class` to `.class`... if there IS a difference, it's too trivial to sweat.

Answer (score 1):

Change from:

```
$('this').id();
```

To:

```
$(this).attr('id')
```

- `this` is a keyword in javascript and not a string.
- There is no `id` function in jQuery, you get the id with `.attr('id')`.
  `id` is a property of DOM elements. so you can use this: `this.id`

---

```
$('.question').click(function() {
    qid = this.id;
    mytarget = '#' + qid + 'ans';
    toggleSlide();
});​
```

Comment: @user1354606. Read the notes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do:  `qid = $('this').id();`

do: `qid = $(this).attr('id');`   without the single quotes

Comment: what is `$(...).id()`? the is no such `id` function.

Comment: @gdoron, you are right.  Focused on the this vs 'this'.   Now displaying the right solution.

Comment: Thank you gdoron. I'm not sure where I got the idea that .id() was a thing. I wrote this on a car trip with no internet, doing research on my phone, and must have picked up the function without reading the context.

Comment: @gdoron. Don't worry, I wasn't drunk.

Answer (score 0):

```
function toggleSlide(mytarget) {
  if ($(mytarget).css('display')=='none'){
      $(mytarget).slideDown(600, 'swing');}

  else if ($(mytarget).css('display')=='block'){
         $(mytarget).slideUp(600, 'swing');}
});
```

when you call the function you should pass the pararmeter:

```
  qid = $(this).id();
  mytarget= '#' + qid + 'ans';
  toggleSlide(mytarget);
```